# Pretty print output in nested loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, multiple-columns, pretty-print

I have a nested loop like so:

```
for a in b.keys():
    for c in b[a]:
        out = '%-30s %s' % (c, a)
        space = out.count(' ')
        split = space * '-'
        print '\t%-30s %s  %-10s' % (c, split, a)
```

So the result is:

```
test1         ------- something1
test23sdfsf   ----- dsffdgdgfddfsdf
```

But what I want is:

```
test1 -------------- something1
test23sdfsf -------- dsffdgdgfddfsdf
```

Comment: You could use `ljust()`: `out = "%s %s" % (c.ljust(maxwidth, '-'), a)`

Comment: @ It doesn't do what I said in question.

Comment: I think this should be an answer zondo, because ljust() is far more pythonic that the curly-bracket-madness below.

Comment: @J.J: Done.  Will you give the first up-vote? :)

Comment: That was the first thing I did when i saw it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a maxwidth of `30`, do the following:

```
for a in b.keys():
    for c in b[a]:
        print("%s %s" % (c.ljust(30, '-'), a))
```

Comment: Good answer. this is space missing after first collumn. `test1-------------- something1`. How can bi fixed?

Comment: In py2:   `print (c+' ').ljust(20,'-') , a`

Comment: @MLSC: As J.J said, you can just add a space: `print('%s %s" % ((c+' ').ljust(30, '-'), a))`

Answer (score 0):

How about using the following:

```
Test: {0:15} Something {1}".format(Variable,AnotherVar)
```

You can calculate the numbers based on the length.

Adding more example:

```
>>> a="test"
>>> b="another_one"
>>> "A: {0:20} B {1}".format(a,b) 'A: test                 B another_one'
>>> "A: {0:15} B {1}".format(a,b) 'A: test            B another_one'
>>> "A: {0:4} B {1}".format(a,b) 'A: test B another_one'
```

You can also use a variable for the second number in the first {} based on the length of strings you want to print.

Comment: How ccan I change the example?

Comment: I have posted more examples. You need to calculate the remaining distance between the string using the length of the first string.

Comment: How can I put `-` between them as I refer in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the same example for my solution in [nested arguments and complex examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

```
for a in b.keys():
    for c in b[a]:
        print '{key:{fill}{align}20} {item}'.format(key=key + ' ', fill='-', align='<', item=b[key])
```

Comment: Where is `c` in your answer?